# Android NDK. Очень много ABI: armeabi, armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a... Под какую из них реально стоит строить нативные .so-либы?

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-ndk, arm

armeabi, armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64, mips, mips64...

Ну, armeabi - вроде понятно. Эта вроде архитектура на всех (или почти на всех) реальных гаджетах.
x86 - вроде тоже понятно. Это прежде всего для Genymotion и прочих эмуляторов, где Android x86.

А остальные?

Будет ли идеальным решением просто построить либу под все ABI? А если нет возможности протестить везде, а только на x86 и armeabi?

И почему столько armов: armeabi, armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a? Какой из них актуальнее? Как определить, какой поддерживается моим гаджетом? Могут ли быть несколько сразу?

Answer (score 6):

*x86* - это прежде всего процессоры *Intel Atom*, которые установлены в немалое число реальных устройств, а не эмуляторы. Эмулятор, как раз может эмулировать любую архитектуру, независимо от архитектуры процессора, на котором хостится - на то он и эмулятор. Вы можете в этом убедится сами, посмотрев на список образов для эмуляции:

[image: scrn]

Минимальным набором поддерживаемых архитектур является набор `APP_ABI := x86 armeabi`. Далее следует определиться, будет ли ваше приложение использовать дополнительные возможности архитектуры *armeabi-v7a*, например *NEON* - если это так, то данную архитектуру тоже следует включить в список ([расширенный список инструкций arm-v7](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/ndk/guides/abis.html#v7a)) - на самом деле, сейчас практически все ARM процессоры, как минимум v7

В последнее время устройства с процессорами на 64-ех битной архитектуре все чаще появляются в продаже, поэтому их тоже стоит учесть.

Точно проигнорировать можно mips/mips64

Узнать, какая архитектура у вашего устройства, можно по спецификации процессора, который оно использует. Например, *Qualcomm Snapdragon 820 - [ARM-V8A](http://system-on-a-chip.specout.com/l/1170/Qualcomm-Snapdragon-820-MSM8996)*. Так же в маркете можно найти программы, которые покажут системную информацию.

Несколько архитектур ARM в одном процессоре быть не может, но каждая следующая включает предыдущую, то есть в ARM-V7 включен ARM, в ARM-V8 - ARM-V7. По факту, самая актуальная сейчас ARM-платформа - ARM-V7, на ней построено абсолютное большинство действующих процессоров, но ARM-V8 активно наступает.
Разница в ARM-архитектурах очевидна, каждая следующая - шаг в эволюции, добавляются новые возможности на уровне железного ядра.

Вы можете указать собрать библиотеку под все abi и это будет хорошим решением, если итоговый размер приложения вас устроит - каждая дополнительная платформа - новые файлы, которые имеют размер.

[Официальное руководство](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/ndk/guides/abis.html) по этому вопросу.

Comment: > Эмулятор, как раз может эмулировать любую архитектуру
На вашем скриншоте, как я понимаю, AVD. Он может и любую. Но очень требователен к железу, иначе жутко тормозит, юзаю Genymotion, а там вроде только x86.

Comment: А что насчет x86_64? Какой вообще смысл делать 64-разрядные библиотеки, если можно делать 32-разрядные, которые работают и на x86 и на x86_64?

Comment: @user204455 Ну не знаю, что там с Genymotion и его архитектурами, факт остается фактом - поддержка x86 нужна в первую очередь для большого количества реальных устройств на Android с процессором Intel, и в последнюю очередь для эмулятора Genymotion.

Comment: AVD во второй реинкарнации (Android Studio 2.*) обрел намного больше подвижности, однако, касательно ОС Windows, только в сочетании с "железной" технологией виртуализации - HAXM, которая доступна только в относительно современных процессорах Intel. На семействе Linux отлично поддерживается и аппаратная виртуализация, реализованная и в процессорах AMD (через QEMU)- там все гораздо веселее работает.

Comment: насчет х86_64 самый актуальный вопрос современности - зачем это все надо, если прирост производительности весьма незначителен. Однозначного ответа пока нет, но традиционно требуется поддерживать для оптимизации. (сама технология arch64 ,в частности, позволяет адресоваться к большему количеству ОЗУ, если из наглядного, поэтому ее появление оправдано, но в плане поддержки 64-битного кода все туманно).

Comment: А много ли вообще гаджетов с x86-64?

Comment: @user204455 Видимо пока состоялся только анонс процессора *Intel Atom Z3480* и серийных устройств еще нет, но под эту лавочку вроде как подписались Lenovo (Moto) и ASUS. Печально и то, что сам Android до сих пор не поддерживает полноценно 64-ех битные приложения, так как сам является 32-ух битным. Думаю, что на ближайшие пару-тройку лет х86_64 можно смело вычеркивать из списка, в то время, как ARM64 уже есть серийные устройства (на том же snapdragon 820 и mediatek MT6795)

Comment: Спс.Спс.Спс.Спс.