# Android, SDK и API. Что это и зачем?

Tags: android, android-sdk, sdk

Пытаюсь разобраться в теме. Вот как я нашел-вижу (поправляйте, если что не так понял / прочитал). Буду показывать и задавать вопросы на основе своего приложения.

1. `minSdkVersion = 14`. Созданное приложение будет работать на API >=14. Даже на самых последних андроидах. Выставляется при создании проекта и целесообразно задавать самый минимальный API, потому что больше охват устройств.
2. `compileSdkVersion = 26`. Версия API с которой компилируется приложение. Т.е. раз стоит 26 и оно работает, значит на версиях ниже оно тоже будет работать 100%. Значит наше приложение будет работать в пределах от 14 до 26 API
3. `targetSdkVersion = 26`. Это как рецензия, что я протестировал это приложение на API 26 и оно работает корректно. Никакого функционала в себе не несет.

Вопросы:

1. Я верно все понял?
2. Почему `compileSdkVersion` и `targetSdkVersion` выставилось 26, если у меня скачана API 27, 28? стоит ли в build.gradle менять значения с 26 на 27/28 ?
3. Через некоторое время выходит телефон с API 30. приложение будет работать на нем?
4. Где посмотреть разрядность приложения х32 / х64 ? на что это вообще влияет?

Я во всех этих тонкостях не понимаю. Всё что адекватное нашел и понял - написал. остальное - темный лес.

Comment: №3 - Да, №4 - разрядность важна только для нативных библиотек, байткод не имеет такого параметра.

Answer (score 4):

minSdkVersion - минимальная версия API, на которой может быть запущена ваша программа. Этот параметр не только расширяет охват устройств, но и обязывает вас использовать возможности только этого (и ранее вышедших) API. Указав данный параметр = 1, вы вынужденны будете писать свой код, как будто андроид только вышел и 27 обновлений апи как будто и не было, включая все те новые классы и методы, что появились за эти 27 обновлений - это изощренное издевательство над собой и на практике доступно единицам.
Однако, любому разработчику хотелось бы и "покрыть" как можно больше устройств и использовать все возможности последнего апи. На помощь тут приходят библиотеки поддержки ([support library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/)), которые подключаются в виде отдельного модуля и дублируют некоторые возможности новых апи, чтобы разработчик мог их использовать в более ранних версиях. Таких библиотек довольно много (смотрите ссылку) и каждая решает определенную задачу (например AppCompat позволяет использовать интерфейс Material на апи ниже 21).
 На сегоняшний день библиотеки поддержки сами имеют ограничение по минимальной версии до апи 14 (что соответствует android 4.0), так что для наибольшего и сравниельно безболезненного охвата устройств значение minSDKversion можно устанавливать равным 14 (при этом мы [теряем 0.2% устройств](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/), что вполне разумная плата). На практике данное значение можно увеличить и до 16 (android 4.1) без существенных потерь.
ps: в настроящее время происходит миграция support-библиотек в пакеты androidX и JetPack, это нужно учесть в дальнейшем.

targetSDKversion указывает "совместимость" с определенным апи. Данный параметр оказывает такое влияние, что указав его, к примеру = 1, вы получите интерфейс (вид виджетов) первого андроида, даже если запустите такое приложение на последней версии или указав значение меньше 23, ваша программа не будет запрашивать runtime permision, на устройствах с  апи больше 23 (будет работать в режиме эмуляции таких разрешений). Частично эффект такой, что программа будет считать, что она выполняется в указанном данным параметром апи, даже если на реальном устройстве другое апи (но здесь есть нюансы, как всегда). Параметр рекомендуется указывать по последнему релизному апи (сегодня это 28) во избежании трудностей, непонятного поведения и тех самых нюансов.

compileSDKversion указывает с помощью какого апи будет компилироваться ваша программа (из какого апи брать классы для компиляции кода). Указав данный параметр, например, равным 23, классы и методы более поздних апи будут недоступны (впрочем, они все равно будут недоступны по ограничению minSDKversion). Данный параметр так же рекомендуется указывать по последней релизной версии апи (сегодня это 28). Так же существует такая связь, что мажорная версия библиотеки поддержки не может быть больше значения compileSDKversion (если вы хотите использовать библиотеки версии 28.х.х, то данный параметр не может быть меньше 28-ми)

Указав эти три параметра какими то цифрами, ваше приложение будет запускаться на всех устройствах, от указанного в minSDKversion до текущего актуального, то есть указывая compileSDKversion = 26 ваше приложение будет работать и на апи 30, когда оно выйдет (ограничить устройства "сверху" можно только параметорм maxSDKversion, но он обычно не указывается вовсе)

разрядность процессора в "классическом" андроид-приложении не учитывается от слова совсем. Данный параметр будет актуален, когда вы решите использовать нативный С/С++ код в вашем приложении и нужно будет определяться [с подключаемыми компиляторами С](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/500823/177345) (для каждой архитектуры процессоров он свой)

Comment: "будут недоступны по ограничению minSDKversion" - вот тут только не согласен. Пример: minSdkVersion = 14, спокойно вызываю новый FingerprintDialog на Android 9, если выставить правильно остальные два параметра.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja не думаю, что то о чем вы пишите возможно (вызов классов/методов, которые добавлены после указанного минимального апи) без дополнительных аннотаций в коде, как `@RequiresApi` или там `@TargetApi` или иных проверок в самом коде, только указанием "остальных двух параметров", иначе указывать минимальный апи было бы вообще незачем ...

Comment: Возможно, аннотации используются для того чтобы помечать код, но и без них возможно. Когда-то же не было этих аннотаций и все работало через 'if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=...)'

Answer (score 2):

@pavlofff написал верно, но очень много :)
Постараюсь войти в пару предложений.

`minSdkVersion` говорит компилятору какой генерить байткод, чтобы он работал на прошивке с таким минимальным уровнем API; говорит компилятору какие показывать ошибки и предупреждения, чтобы программист не пытался тупо вызвать API новее указанного; говорит устройству, совместимо ли приложение с его прошивкой.

`targetSDKversion` говорит компилятору, какой максимальный уровень API доступен (новые недоступны вообще); говорит устройству, в каком "режиме совместимости" приложение запускать (если он выше, запускать как свое родное).

`compileSDKversion` указывает, какой набор тулзов из Android SDK использовать. Рекомендуют использовать всегда последние.

Остальное - производные из этих правил.

Еще одно важное правило: `minSdkVersion`<=`targetSDKversion`<=`compileSDKversion`

Answer (score 1):

*1) minSdkVersion = 14* - Верно что будет работать с версии 14 и выше, но выставлять минимальный API **нецелесообразно**, т.к. android версий 2.х.х менее 1%. Используя API версии 14, ты лишаешься возможностей доступных в версии скажем 4.х. **ВАЖНО!** Все зависит от конкретных требований к ПО. Чем ниже версия API тем сложнее разработка и поддержка. [История версий Android](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9_Android).

По вопросам:

3) Новые API поддерживают старые, Java и если я верно понял Android придерживаются обратной совместимости.

4) Откуда необходимость в такой информации? Разрядность ОС или поддержка приложением 64 архитектуры? Я это к тому, что иногда при обучении несет не в ту сторону, и много времени может уйти на изучение не совсем ценной информации.

По остальным вопросам воздержусь отвечать, т.к. не уверен что смогу корректно и понятно объяснить.

P.S. Лично мое мнение. "Темный лес" освещается практикой. Придумай себе проект, поставь задачи (конкретные, а не все возможные фичи и технологии сразу) и постепенно обучаясь реализуй проект. Темных мест будет становиться меньше.